# How to connect database url to AWS RDS AND EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-rds

I have this docker.env file that i need to connect to rds database hosted in AWS i have set up all security groups and EC2 instances.But i am not able to connect to the database somehow i have followed all steps for https://github.com/outline/outline-onprem/tree/main

Here is my sample docker.env file that i am using

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://username:password@hostname:5432/outline
```

When i run the command "sudo docker-compose run --rm outline yarn db:migrate" and use the database main user with privilages for username and passoword i get this error

```
ERROR: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN username
```

This project is the open source https://github.com/outline/outline-onprem/tree/main

https://docs.getoutline.com/s/13dec265-c002-4c73-8025-75981f29b0d0

Comment: I would simplify by using a dedicated database client to confirm you can connect to your DB from same host where your docker container runs ... this gives youi a known good db client so you can focus on getting the auth and URL values working

Comment: Did you open port 5432 on your AWS public interface?

Comment: yes i opened the port

Comment: That error suggests it's reading `username` as the host name part of the URL.  In the real credentials, is there any interesting punctuation?